# Undefined error when trying to load XML

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a big 400kb xml file.

When i try to load it by using:

- IXMLDocument's LoadXMLData or
- CreateOLEObject('MSXML2.DOMDocument.4.0')' Load method

I get Undefined error in both methods.
I took the file and pasted to xml validation webpage, it valides ok...

What else can i do?

By the way, Is there any max length for the attribute in the element?

### EDIT

it seems that it cannot load long attribute ...
i have part of another xml in the xml's attribute value ...

```
An error pops up: Undefined error. Line: 1 (here is the begining of the xml)
Class of the exception is: EDOMParseError
```

Generally i would like to achive something like this:

```
<doc type="X223">
  <params id_param="51" value="XML_1" />
  <params id_param="52" value="XML_2" />
  <params id_param="53" value="XML_3" />
</doc>
```

Comment: ...and how long is that attribute ? Could you minimize the problem and post some XML sample showing such long attribute ?

Comment: @TLama, maybe it is a bad approach, but I have 400kb xml in another one. That second xml is placed in an attribute ...

Comment: Have you stored that XML inside XML as `CDATA` ?

Comment: No, that xml is stored and escaped in xml attribute, something like: <innerData value="XmlInside, signs escaped. This have 400kb length" />

Comment: Store it to `CDATA` and I bet your problem disappear.

Comment: Ok Will try, except for this, nothing can be done with the existing xml format ... ?

Comment: I think there is something more fundamental happening here. Make a copy of the XML, cut it down to about 4k in size, and try reading it. I suspect it won't load either. Fix that, then try the big one.

Comment: @TLama please write your proposed answer as the answer.

Comment: @mj2008 15kb cut down xml can be loaded...

Comment: @John If you have found the answer, please write it up fully and post it yourself. This will help others in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can change your schema, prefer to store your inner XML files to [`CDATA section`](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp), if not then try to think about following.

Parser failed on your element attribute value most probably due to quote character contained in an XML file you've tried to store there. Consider the following case for instance:

```
<params id_param="51" value="<innerxmlattributevalue="value">"/>
```

As you can see, you might confuse parser with the quote char from that inner XML, so that it could take the above line as:

```
<params id_param="51" value="<innerxmlattributevalue="
value">"/>     <-- here is expected to be another attribute or closing bracket
```

The easiest you can do when you want to keep your current schema is to escape all quoting characters of your inner XML file.

From the [`RFC 2629`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2629) specification (emphased by me):

> Make sure that all attributes values are quoted, e.g., `"<example name='value'>"`, If the value contains one of the quoting characters,
> then use the other to quote the value, e.g., `"<example name='"'>"`,
> **If the value contains both quoting characters, then use one of them to quote the value, and replace occurrances of that character in the
> attribute value with either `'&apos;'` (apostrophe) or `"&quot;"`
> (quotation), e.g., `"<example name='"&apos;"'>"`**.

Comment: Putting long value into CDATA section did the trick. By the way, I was escaping all characters, it was just the length xml parser hasn't wanted to accept. Also the interesting thing is that when passing that xml into mssql db, and loading it by using prepare document generated also that unspecified error, however using XML type alleviated the problem.

Comment: I've tried to find a reference describing length limits of attribute values, but it seems there's nothing official about it. And without seeing your real implementation I've been suspecting the unescaped quotes. Even though, `CDATA` is the right place for it.